# Get Value of Previous Page Controll's

Tags: jquery, asp.net, query-string

My page consists of 4 tab(Using a Jquery Accordian).

Tab 1.) User selects Device Make and Model(Default.aspx)

Tab 2.)User Confirms Our Buyback price(GetPrice.aspx is loaded into Tab2)

Tab 3.)User Enters Contact information(Default.aspx)

Tab 4.)Confirmation Page Displaying Users Information(Conf.aspx is loaded into Tab3)

The problem arises because I need my CodeBehind(on Conf.aspx) to have access to the user's contact information. If I passed the value's through query string, it would enable users to tamper with it and insert erroneous information into my database. Keep in mind, all of this is done WITHOUT postback.

So I need:

1.)A way to tamper-proof the Query String(keep in my the query string would consist of a Phone number,email address,state,city,zip,etc)

OR

2.)A simple way to grab the values of the previous field(From Conf.aspx CodeBehind: A Way to retreive the values of the controlls on Default.aspx)

Sorry for the long block of text, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `Server.Transfer` or [`LinkButton.PostbackUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.postbackurl.aspx) to redirect to `Conf.aspx`? Then you can access all controls via [`Page.PreviousPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) directly.

Comment: Actually, I use Jquery to load Conf.aspx. The submit button is a non-asp controll. When clicked, it triggers a jquery function to 1.)Load the next tab, and minimize the current tab. It is loaded using this:$('#conf').load("conf.aspx");

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that separate webforms for each tab is necessary.
You could probably re-architect your solution to be service oriented. Your logic can be available via webservice and your tabs can all be in the same view. Doing this the webform way will be more complicated.

Comment: GetPrice.aspx(Second Tab), accesses my database to fetch the price. I choose to do it this way, so there was no postback. If I keep the content all on one page(Default.aspx), Postback would be neccesary

Comment: The service can access the database, and you can get to the service via javascript, so postback is not required.